# Access class that attribute is affecting from said attribute

Tags: c#, class, types

Whenever the `TestAttribute` attribute is called on a class, I would like to add that type to a list. How can I do that?

Example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TestAttribute : Attribute {
    public TestAttribute() {
        // Add type to list
    }
}

public static class TypeHolder {
    public static List<Type> Types = new List<Type>();
}

[Test]
public static class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(TypeHolder.Types.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: attributes aren't "called" - they are entirely inert unless acted on by code that looks for them; are you looking for the code you'd need to explicitly look for them on given types?

Comment: You should initialize your `Types` property in your static class like `public static List<Type> Types = new List<Type>()` so that it's not null when you first access it. But you should also be aware of issues surrounding static types, especially if your type can be called in a multithreaded environment.